# File Writer Fails

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I have the following code:

```
private void Write(string path, string txt)
{
    string dir =Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    try
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(dir)) { Directory.CreateDirectory(dir); }
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Create(path).Dispose();
            using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path))
            {
                tw.WriteLine(txt);
                tw.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
            {
                tw.WriteLine(txt);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log error;
    }
}
```

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)+"\\html\\Static_1.html"` is passed in the path parameter and some html text is passed for the txt parameter. Code fails at `File.Create()`. I get the following error:

> Could not find file 'C:\Users\Xami Yen\Documents\html\Static_1.html

What is wrong with this code? Can't figure it out.

Comment: you dont have to create the file to write to it

Comment: You need to provide a path for the directory.

Comment: Could you please post the full stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: File.WriteAllText does all this in one line for you

Comment: Also, have you considered using [File.AppendAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext?view=netframework-4.7.2) or [File.WriteAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: Do you have permissions to write in that folder? Because the code above doen't trigger that error on my system

Comment: @RuiJarimba Here is the stack trace at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
at System.IO.File.Create(String path)
at NYCSLContent.ExcelImport.Write(String path, String txt) line 94

Comment: Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments is a folder where the logged in user has full permissions on.

Comment: Check all the exceptions that can be thrown in [File.Create documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.create?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 1):

MSDN Documentation:
`File.WriteAllText` method creates a new file, write the contents to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.

Also, please make sure you have Write permissions to the newly created folder.

```
private void Write(string path, string txt)
{
    var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    try
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(dir)) Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
        File.WriteAllText(path, txt);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log error;
    }
}
```

Comment: That works. I assumed that Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments has the write permissions for the logged in user but that does not seem to be correct. So I was getting the error. Once I changed the directory path, it all worked just fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The Directory.Exists check can also be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void Write(string path, string txt, bool appendText=false)
{
    try
    {
        string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

        if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
        }

        if (appendText)
        {
            // Appends the specified string to the file, creating the file if it does not already exist.
            File.AppendAllText(path, txt);
        }
        else
        {
            // Creates a new file, write the contents to the file, and then closes the file.
            // If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.
            File.WriteAllText(path, txt);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log error
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex}");
    }
}
```